# My working script won't launch from a shortcut

Tags: python, shortcut

I'm trying to create a python script that picks a file at random from a folder and runs it. I tried it at first exclusively with a list shortcuts to exe files (specifically video games) and it works exactly as intended-- I can double-click the .py file and it runs a random file from the directory referenced in the code.

```
from os import walk, system
from random import randint

GameList=[]

for root, dirs, files in walk("C:\\Users\\awh.1998\\Desktop\\Gaming\\Games"):
    for filename in files:
        GameList.append(filename) #adds all games in 'Games' folder to GameList as strings

RandomGame=GameList[randint(0,(len(GameList)-1))]
RandomGamePath = f"C:\\Users\\awh.1998\\Desktop\\Gaming\\Games\\{RandomGame}"

system('cmd /k {}'.format(RandomGamePath))
print(RandomGamePath)
```

I tried to generalize this for broader use, with the main difference being that in the newer script, I've also used the os module to automatically find the path. The code works perfectly when I open the Python Interpreter and launch the script from the interpreter itself, but when I try to use a shortcut (which works perfectly for the other script), it just opens a blank console in the interpreter and does nothing.

```
from random import randint

def splitkeep(string, delimiter):
    Split = string.split(delimiter)
    Split = [substr + delimiter for substr in Split]
    Split = Split[:-1]
    output = "".join(Split)
    return output

Path = getcwd() #defines current directory as string
Path = splitkeep(Path, "\\")

FileList=[]

for root, dirs, files in walk(Path):
    for filename in files:
        FileList.append(filename) #adds all files in folder to FileList as strings

FileList.remove('RandomFile.py')

RandomFile=FileList[randint(0,(len(FileList)-1))]
RandomFilePath=Path+RandomFile

system('cmd /k {}'.format(RandomFilePath))
print(Path)
print(FileList)
print(RandomFilePath)
```

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed - maybe it will display it in console and you will see which part can makes problem.

Comment: in second script you forgot `from os import *` to use `getcwd()` and `walk()`

Comment: `walk()` can get filenames from subfolder but it doesn't add this subfolder to value in `filename` and you can get incorrect path - so you can try to run `program.exe` when you may need `subfolder/program.exe` - you should use `os.path.join(root, filename)` to get correct path.

Comment: I must have missed the first line when copying the script-- I do in fact have "from os import walk, system, getcwd" in the very first line. The script does work exactly as intended without issues when I open Idle and launch it from Idle's menu. It opens a random file from the folder one directory level higher. It's probably worth noting that the "print" outputs don't show up in the python shell until after I close command prompt. My problem is that the script doesn't work at all when opened from a shortcut, but works perfectly when opened manually from Idle.

Comment: first you could use `logging` (or normal file0 to send information which line was executed - maybe this way you could get which line makes problem. When you run from shortcut then it may use different folder as `Current Working Directory` and then `getcwd() ` will gives different folder then you expect. You may need to use `sys.argv[0]` with `os.path.dirname()` and `os.path.abspath()` to get folder with your script.

Comment: use `logging` or save information in normal file to see what code is doing. You can also use `try/except` to catch error and then you can save it in `logging` or file. It the only method to test/debug code when you double-click. And without these information there is no solution.

Comment: Okay, this is helpful. I'm not sure if I'm using the logging module properly. I have five `print` lines at the end of the code now, and here are the outputs:
1. `print(Path)` gives `C:\Users\awh.1998\Desktop\Test`
2. `print(FileList)` gives `['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt']`
3. `print(RandomFilePath)` gives `C:\Users\awh.1998\Desktop\Test\1.txt`, although this output varies given that it randomly picks one of the 3 files in FileList.
4. `print(str(argv[0]))` gives `C:\Users\awh.1998\Desktop\Test\Random\RandomFile.py`
5. `print(logging.info())` gives `<function info at 0x0000018265B779D0>`

Comment: use `logging` to safe information in file, not to display on screen. if you don't know how to use `logging` then use normal file and write information to this file - `open(), write(), close()`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not sure exactly how to do that. What parameters should I put in `write()` in order to actually print debug info to a normal file?

Comment: if you can see text from `print()` then you don't have to use file but only display on screen all what you have. `print(Path)`, `print("inside for-loop", root, dirs, files)`, etc -  use it to see which part of code is executed, how it change values in variables, etc. It is method to observe what code is doing. Maybe this way you see something strange in variables or you see that it loops all time the same folder or folder is empty, etc. This is called `"print debuging"` and it can be simple then learning how to use real debuger.

Comment: Okay, this is helpful. However, all variables are exactly what they should be when reviewing the output after print debugging. To clarify, I cannot see any output whatsoever when using the shortcut— no matter what I add to the code, a black Idle window pops up but says nothing.

Comment: `IDLE` windows or console window ? Did you double click to run python script in  `IDLE ` ? Why not directly to `python.exe` ? If it says nothing then you can try to write messages to file - maybe it runs but it can't only display. It behaves very strange and I don't have more ideas. And I don't use Windows to test this behavior.